# Page size won't change even after using geometry package

Tags: margins, geometry

I'm trying to change the page size of my thesis document. As adviced in other threads, the graphics package can be used for this purpose. I currently have the following command where I also specified the page margins.

```
\usepackage[pass,paperheight=26cm,paperwidth=19cm,top=20mm,bottom = 15mm, left = 30mm, right = 30mm ]{geometry}
```

On the thesis document, the pdf page size wont change from 8.50x11inch. The thesis document contains inputs from 4 other files (4 chapters) too. If I create a new tex file and have the same command, the pdf document will have the correct dimensions. For instance,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[paperheight=26cm,paperwidth=19cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

hello world

\end{document}
```

Works perfectly. Can anybody tell me why it wouldn't work in my previous file?

Comment: Omit the `pass` option, as it basically disables all `geometry` options, except of `verbose` and `showframe`, see the manual please, it is stated on the 12th page, at least in the version I have on my disk...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) (section **5.7 Other options**):

> **pass**
>
> disables all of the `geometry` options and calculations except `verbose` and `showframe`. It
>   is order-independent and can be used for checking out the page layout of the
>   document class, other packages and manual settings without `geometry`.

Remove this from your options and `geometry` will set the page layout accordingly.